# Is SAT an existential question?

Tags: satisfiability, decision-problem

Some sources state that an algorithm that solves the SAT problem not only needs to decide whether a given existentially-quantified formula is satisfiable or not, but, additionally, in the case where the formula is satisfiable, it does need to provide a satisfying assignment. Is this true or not?

I am bit confused, since I thought the SAT problem would just be an existential question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40926/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29482/755

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The SAT problem is a **decision** problem. It means that an algorithm that solves SAT must answer `true` or `false`, and not necessarily find a satisfying assignment.

However, as many decision problems, there is a **functional** problem associated to SAT, that asks to find a satisfying assignment when there exists one.

There is a polynomial time reduction from the functional problem to the decision problem. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Finding_a_satisfying_assignment) to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 12):

If you have variables x1 to xn, and you decide in polynomial time whether the problem can be satisfied or not, then if it can be satisfied, you set x1 = true and check if it can still be satisfied. If not you set x1 = false, which can be satisfied.

Then you set x2 = true, and if that cannot be satisfied you set x2 = false. And so on, and so on. So if SAT could be solved in polynomial time, you could find a solution in polynomial time quite easily. A similar approach could be used for TSP, for example.