# Finding a solution to a satisfiable formula

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability

I know that it is as hard to find a solution to a SAT formula, as it is to decide it has a solution at all. See the answer to:
[Is finding a solution of a satisfiability problem harder than deciding satisfiability?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29482/4287)

Are there also families of formulas for which it is guaranteed that there is a solution, but it is hard to find one?

Comment: Not an expert, but I would expect that the only measure of difficulty that could usefully describe an instance *across all possible solution algorithms* would be the ratio nSatisfyingAssignments / nPossibleAssignments.

Comment: Related: [complexity class TFNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFNP).

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, a hash function is a prime example of a function (which can be modelled by a very complex binary formula of its inputs) where it is easy to find the output given an input, but finding an input which matches an output is very hard.

But since we generated the original output we know that there must be a solution.

This construction requires the ability to forget information (the original input) however.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know if any families of SAT formulas are hard since we don't yet know if P and NP are distinct complexity classes.

[Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem) gives six families of formulas that are known to be *easy*.

SAT formulas based on reductions from hard cryptography problems are assumed to be hard for the same reason the source problem is hard.  Since a crypto problem involves finding a key that's known to exist, the resulting SAT instances will have at least one satisfying assignment even though such instances are probably hard.